# Eclipse project which depends on another one - Class not found exception

Tags: eclipse, classpath

I've got 2 projects in the same workspace where one of them is added as a "required project" to the properties of the other one.

If I try to run the project I keep getting ClassNotFound Exceptions (probably because the bin directory isn't part of the runtime classpath?!)

Is there any nice way to fix this?
Maybe there is any solution where my teammates who work on the same project (via SVN) don't have to do any configuration on their machines.

Thanks a lot in advance,
Martin

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning and rebuilding your work space.

Comment: right click -> properties -> build path... do you see the required project in Projects tab ?